# Why does npm not run prepublishOnly in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, continuous-integration, monorepo

When developing a monorepo tool (yamrt) designed to publish npm packages in a ci/cd environment, prepublishOnly scripts were not being run in some runners.

All tests are passing in circleci image circleci/node:12

Same tests fail in the official node:12 image

Why?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that circleci/node:12 image adds a user to run builds, while node:12 does not have a user, and therefore processes there are run as root. npm refuses to run prepublishOnly scripts as root, with this rather cryptic message:

```
npm WARN lifecycle yamrt-node12-test@0.0.1~prepublishOnly: cannot run in wd yamrt-node12-test@0.0.1 echo PREPUBLISHING NM (wd=.)
```

An obvious fix is to add a user to the ci builder image, which is of course good sense in any case.

```
RUN groupadd ciuser && useradd -ms /bin/bash ciuser -g ciuser
USER ciuser
```